# MySQL select for three fields (like filter)

Tags: php, mysql, select, filter, where-clause

There is a table `table`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `main` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nid` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table`(
      `main`, `sid`, `rid`, `nid`
  ) VALUES(
    1, 8, 1, null),
    (1, null, null, "hello"),
    (2, 8, 1, null),
    (2, 1, 2, null),
    (1, 1, 2, null)
```

**I need to find field `main`, where records have next data:**

```
sid = 8, rid=1, nid = null ;
sid = null, rid = null, nid = "hello"
sid=1, rid=2, nid = null
```

Steps for example:

1. First, we get data: sid = 8, rid=1, nid = null
2. With this data we make select-query and result are two records: main =1 and main =2,
3. First, we add one condition: sid = null, rid = null, nid = "hello"
4. And now query must filter and return one record where main=1

Comment: That's not a table. A table has a PRIMARY KEY ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT main FROM `table` where sid IS NULL AND rid IS NULL AND nid = 'hello' AND 
main IN (SELECT main FROM `table` WHERE sid = 8 AND rid=1 AND nid IS NULL);
```

Hope This will be helpful to You.

Comment: It's help for this situation.. And how to be with dynamic data (many sid, rid, nid)?